# To find out the highest value, quarter from dates from table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to retrieve the highest paid employee name, salary and the respective quarter from the below table with the help of dates.

```
Table name: Emp
------------------
Empname     Salary      Date
Hunter      3260000     31aug2011
Antony      2000000     30nov2011
Mark        1800000     1dec2011
Gabriel     2300000     31oct2011
Christian   2400000     31oct2011
Gabriel     2250000     30Nov2011
Hunter      2280000     30sep2011
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Oracle - 11g

Comment: Do you want to see the highest **overall** salary, or the highest **per quarter**

Comment: Overall highest salary and it falls under which quarter of the mentioned year.

Answer (score 6):

```
 SELECT empname, 
        salary,
        to_char("DATE", 'Q')
 FROM (
    SELECT empname, 
           salary,
           "DATE",
           dense_rank() over (order by salaray desc) as rnk
    FROM emp
 ) t
 where rnk = 1
```

Using a reserved word (`DATE`) as a column name is not a very good idea...

Comment: +1 and... probably the user need dense_rank() over (**partition by trunc(date,'Q')** order by salaray desc) as rnk

Comment: @FlorinGhita: it was not clear to me from the original question if the salary should be highest overall, or the highest per quarter.

Comment: Can u pl give me queries 2 scenarios:
1. Overall highest salary and its corresponding quarter need to be displayed.
2. Highest Sal per quarter and it should display which quarter and who got highest pay.

Comment: @shubcbe: Is this homework? For 2) see Florin's comment. You need to do some of the work yourself.

Comment: No its not home work, Its a puzzle to find out which function needs to be used. Thanks.